# Internal testing build doesn't authenticate with google play games

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-play-services, google-play-console

App is developed in Unity. The .apk if shared externally works and im able to sign in with GPGS. However the internal testing build downloaded from Play Store wont let me authenticate. I rolled out the internal testing with all the terms and service accepted. I selected the email-list of testers as well. No idea why it works on a externally shared .apk but not when downloaded through google play tester link. Only think I have done so far is disable billing for the app though I have 300$ worth of credit due to first sign in. Since it works outside of playstore download I assume the billing isn't the problem?

I rolled out the internal testing with everything set. I was expecting it to sign in with GPGS properly as it does when the app installed via externally shared .apk file.

Comment: Are you talking about the internal testing track or internal app sharing?